# Consume WebApi with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am starting with AngularJS, and I have done this example:

A simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>First Demo</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="prdController">
            <div>
                <h2>All Products - With Angular</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
                        {{ formatItem(product) }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Search by ID</h2>
                <input type="text" ng-model="prodId" size="5" />
                <input type="button" value="Search" ng-click="find(prodId);" />
            </div>
            <strong ng-show="loading">loading..</strong>
            <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ProductController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have this controller:

```
(function () {
    var uri = '/demo.WebApi/api/products';
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.controller('prdController', function ($scope, $http) {
        //debugger;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.products = [];
        //$scope.prodId = 0;
        $scope.error = '';

        $http.get(uri)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.products = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
                $scope.loading = false;
        });

        $scope.formatItem = function (item) {
            //debugger;
            return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
        }

        $scope.find = function (id) {
            debugger;
            $scope.loading = true;
            $http.get(uri + '/' + id)
            .success(function (data) {
                debugger;
                $scope.products = [];
                $scope.products = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
        };
    });
})();
```

The $http.get method works great, and I can get my product list. In my html page, I see the formated product list:

```
Tomato Soup: $1
Yo-yo: $3.75
Hammer: $16.99
```

But when I try to search one product, putting an Id in the input text prodId, I can´t see the product. I can see the data returned with the values of my product, but it can´t renders in my page. The list is presented as showned below:

```
undefined: $undefined
undefined: $undefined
undefined: $undefined
undefined: $undefined
```

I get 3 lines of the first list, plus one more line with my searched product.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Comment: can you show the signature of your Web API method? the URL structure might vary based on the arguments you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

Does the GET by ID return an array with a single object item or an object?

I suspect the error is that it's returning a single object, such that when you are assigning the return data to the $scope.products:

```
$scope.products = [];
$scope.products = data;
```

products is no longer an array. ng-repeat also accepts object collections and my guess is that the undefined output you are seeing is the result of each key being passed to the formatItem function. Try changing the above to:

```
$scope.products = [data];
```

If the data IS an array, there is definitely another issue.